# Can I avoid references to cells in other sheets from breaking if I remove/add a row?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheets that has two sheets. One takes entries and a second manipulates content from the first and displays results.

If I remove or add a row, the references in sheet two change, killing the desired content in that same sheet. If I delete row two from sheet one, what becomes row two in sheet one does not replace the content that was in sheet two, instead the cell breaks, referencing a non-existent or irrelevant cell.

I know what's happening. Instead of referencing a position relative to the sheet, it's referencing the actual cell but this not only does that not make sense, it doesn't work for my intended purpose.

Can I change this functionality or is there a better way to approach the issue?

Comment: can you give us some feedback whether the answers give, are appropriate?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra, with the complexity of the sheet I was attempting, none of the solutions posted were viable. I ended up giving up and simplifying the sheet.

Comment: Is there a way to insert a row, delete a row, or sort rows while updating references, so that they remain valid?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to reference columns and not ranges:

Column reference:

```
=SUM(A:A) or =SUM(A30:A)
```

Explicit reference:

```
=SUM(A2:A30)
```

At most, you need to re-populate the formula's. Walk through the spreadsheet I prepared and see the formula's for yourself: [file I prepare with example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdFFXU3B5OEtXcXM5ZnpjOHdhNWMxQlE)

Answer (score 3):

To keep references, I avoid to delete edge cells. Let say I have `SUM(A1:A10)` and I need few more lines. Then I add them between 9 and 10 rows. When deleting, I avoid to delete rows `1` and `10`, others are safe to delete.

If you have reference to another sheet single cell (without formula) - then yes, it is problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a [Named Range](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175)** in the first sheet. Then refer to those cells in the other sheet by the named range.

The named range will refer to those cells even if you insert/delete other rows or columns before it, thus changing their cell numbers.The named range will expand if you insert rows or columns within that range.